# how to grab a block of lines from a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, set

I have a large file which has lines following a pattern like this:

**Headline type  1**

=============================

Common line type 1

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2
```

Some random text

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2

Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

Headline type 2

Some random text

**Headline type 2**

===============================

Common line type 1

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2
```

Some random text

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

My question is how to grab a block of lines in the form of a set like

--------------------------------------------set1------------------------------------------------

**Headline type  1**

=============================

Common line type 1

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2
```

Some random text

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2

Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

Headline type 2

Some random text

--------------------------------------------set2------------------------------------------------

**Headline type  1**

=============================

Common line type 1

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2
```

Some random text

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

Headline type 2

```
Common line type 2

Common line type 2

Common line type 2

Common line type 2
```

---

I do not how to use line "=============================" to indentify start and end of a block of lines.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a comparison inside a for loop to do that.

```
# only need this if you cannot guarantee first line is '===='
start_record = False
# assume you want to store all lines with in same '====' in same list
results = []
for line in file.readlines():
    # converting string to set will get all unique characters 
    # if only ==== exist in a line, start a new list for new block
    if set(line) == {'='}: 
        start_record = True
        results.append([])
        continue 
    if start_record:
        results[-1].append(line)
```